# Wait until the method returns in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm new to Selenium and I have a method in like this

```
public  Test login(String username,String password)
{
    accountName.sendKeys(username);
    passwordField.sendKeys(password);

    signInButton.click();
    return PageFactory.initElements(driver,Test.class);
}
```

Login can take some time to complete. I wish I could wait until `login` method returns before other method calls. Are there any way in selenium to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options to solve this issue. I would recommend you add a fluent wait:

```
   Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
       .pollingEvery(1, SECONDS)
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

   WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
     public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
       return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
     }
   });
```

This will wait for an element to be present that in this example would be an element that is only found on the second page. If after the timeout period it is not found it will throw an error.

The other option is to increase the time of webdriver implicit wait so it will always be able to wait for a longer time, something like:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```